# Cannot access a method call from non-static to non-static class/method

Tags: java, static

I am terribly sorry to have to bother you all with this silly question since I should really know this by now but here goes:

```
public class Toets

private String vak;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Toets
 */
public Toets(String toetsVak)
{
    vak = toetsVak;
    new Vraag();
}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 *
 * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
 * @return    the sum of x and y
 */
public void addVraag(int vraagID, String vraag, String antwoordA, String antwoordB, String antwoordC, String correcteAntwoord)
{
    new Vraag(vraagID, vraag, antwoordA, antwoordB, antwoordC, correcteAntwoord);
}

public void printVraag(int vraagID)
{
    Vraag.printVraag(vraagID);
}
```

which should be called from here:

```
public class Vraag

private int vraagID;
private String vraag;
private String antwoordA;
private String antwoordB;
private String antwoordC;
private String correcteAntwoord;    

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Vraag
 */
public Vraag()
{
    vraagID = 0;
    vraag = "";
    antwoordA = "";
    antwoordB = "";
    antwoordC = "";
    correcteAntwoord = "";
}

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Vraag
 */
public Vraag(int vraagID, String vraag, String antwoordA, String antwoordB, String antwoordC, String correcteAntwoord)
{
    this.vraagID = vraagID;
    this.vraag = vraag;
    this.antwoordA = antwoordA;
    this.antwoordB = antwoordB;
    this.antwoordC = antwoordC;
    this.correcteAntwoord = correcteAntwoord;
}

public void printVraag(int vraagID)
{
    if(this.vraagID == vraagID)
    {
        System.out.println("Vraag " + vraagID + ".");
        System.out.println(vraag);
        System.out.println("A. " + antwoordA);
        System.out.println("B. " + antwoordB);
        System.out.println("C. " + antwoordC);
    }
}
```

}

The thing I am trying to do is create a Test for a school and add questions one by one and print a question in accordance with the designated ID (AKA question number); we are not allowed to use statics so I have looked at ways to accomplish this but I kind of lose it at the Java.lang.reflection stuff.

The thing is that I need to be able to create multiple instances of Vraag and call the print method of each one which I apparently can not do at the moment.

Comment: You can create instance of class and then call that `printVraag()` method.

Comment: It won't even compile for me; I have actually tried that by setting an empty constructor and initiating an object of Vraag when creating the Toets object. But yet it won't let me do it, I understand very well that it won't let me access the method from a non static context since the object I wish to call the method from does not yet exist since it is not initialised at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of providing Vraag as attribute, you simple provide **`List<Vraag>`**.

Everytime when you create new Vraag object simply put into list.

And while printing all attributes of particular object you can filter out record based on passed Id.

Try below code it will help you.

```
class Toets {
    private String vak;
    private List<Vraag> vraagList;

    public Toets(String toetsVak) {
        vak = toetsVak;
    }

    public void addVraag(int vraagID, String att, String antwoordA, String antwoordB, String antwoordC, String correcteAntwoord) {
        vraagList.add(new Vraag(vraagID, att, antwoordA, antwoordB, antwoordC, correcteAntwoord));
    }

    public void printVraag(int vraagID) {
//Java 8 code
        Vraag obj=vraagList.stream().filter(vraag -> vraag.getVraagID()==vraagID).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
        obj.printVraag(vraagID);
    /* Before Java 8
         for(Vraag obj:vraagList){
            if(obj.getVraagID()==vraagID){
                obj.printVraag(vraagID);
            }
        }*/


    }
}

class Vraag {
    private int vraagID;
    private String vraag;
    private String antwoordA;
    private String antwoordB;
    private String antwoordC;
    private String correcteAntwoord;

    public Vraag(int vraagID, String vraag, String antwoordA, String antwoordB, String antwoordC, String correcteAntwoord) {
        this.vraagID = vraagID;
        this.vraag = vraag;
        this.antwoordA = antwoordA;
        this.antwoordB = antwoordB;
        this.antwoordC = antwoordC;
        this.correcteAntwoord = correcteAntwoord;
    }

    public void printVraag(int vraagID) {
        System.out.println("Vraag " + vraagID + ".");
        System.out.println(vraag);
        System.out.println("A. " + antwoordA);
        System.out.println("B. " + antwoordB);
        System.out.println("C. " + antwoordC);
        System.out.println("correcteAntwoord. " + correcteAntwoord);
    }

    public int getVraagID() {
        return vraagID;
    }

    public void setVraagID(int vraagID) {
        this.vraagID = vraagID;
    }

    public String getVraag() {
        return vraag;
    }

    public void setVraag(String vraag) {
        this.vraag = vraag;
    }

    public String getAntwoordA() {
        return antwoordA;
    }

    public void setAntwoordA(String antwoordA) {
        this.antwoordA = antwoordA;
    }

    public String getAntwoordB() {
        return antwoordB;
    }

    public void setAntwoordB(String antwoordB) {
        this.antwoordB = antwoordB;
    }

    public String getAntwoordC() {
        return antwoordC;
    }

    public void setAntwoordC(String antwoordC) {
        this.antwoordC = antwoordC;
    }

    public String getCorrecteAntwoord() {
        return correcteAntwoord;
    }

    public void setCorrecteAntwoord(String correcteAntwoord) {
        this.correcteAntwoord = correcteAntwoord;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly; this puts all the objects of vraag in the list with an int as value/key and that will determine which object of vraag should be used to retrieve the information such as antwoord and the vraag (question itself)?

Comment: Okay, and I have one more issue with the code you provided me (I am grateful do not get me wrong) but the Collectors.toList part in Toets says Variable not found

Comment: Thank you very much so far; I am now having a null pointer exception being thrown after adding a vraag from an instance of toets, but that should be solvable! Once again thank you very much!

Comment: It is already solved; the list was not initiated which I did now so it now creates the list when and Object of Toets is created and I can add Vraag objects and retrieve them without issue.

Comment: Great...!! Keep it up :d

Answer (score 0):

Question is hard to decipher for sure, but I assume you want a list/array or something to store those questions in and that can't be static?

If so, you don't need a static (guess you know what that means) object if a class that has the list isn't created multiple times, it has a list variable but that variable only exists once which I assume is what you want